# Bootstrap no hace slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo este código en bootstrap y no hace el slide. Está cargado el jquery y el javascript de bootstrap. ¿Qué error puedo tener en el código que no hace el slide?

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide mb-3" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">


    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=PRIMERA" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=SEGUNDA" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=TERCERA" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide mb-3" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">


    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=PRIMERA" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=SEGUNDA" />
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x350?text=TERCERA" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El código no tiene errores, deberías visualizarlo sin problema, cómo estás cargando las librerías? Dale en [edit] si necesitas añadir mas información

Comment: esto es lo que tengo en el head     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css">

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para agregar un fragmento de código y funciona correctamente al cargar las librerías desde CDN. Revisa la consola para ver si hay errores.